# Why is this variable changed inside the if block?

Tags: javascript

Why is the global variable `some_var` changed inside the `if` block in this example?

```
<script>
    var some_var = 0;

    var i = 5;
    if (i>2)
    {
        var some_var = 2;
    }
    else
    {}

    console.log(some_var);
</script>
```

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable

Comment: becasue an `if` block does not create a new scope.. it's in the same scope as an existing var with that name so the existing one gets overwrritten

Comment: Also [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score -3):

I'm guessing that if you remove the 'var' inside the if block it works properly. Must be the environment checking for initializations before running the code.